# Magento2: Customer name is not showing on product page

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-session, frontend-error

When the cache is enabled customer name is not showing on the product page.

When the cache is disabled customer name is showing properly on the product page.

**header.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

//$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('about-us'); ?>">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('contact-us'); ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>">My Orders</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('wishlist'); ?>">Wish List</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('ordertracking'); ?>">Track Order</a></li>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Codism\Csr\Block\Index\TopMenu')
    ->setTemplate('Codism_Csr::menu.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>

<?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {?>
<li>Hi, <?php echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); ?></li>
<?php }?>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Are you using custom code to print customer name ?

Comment: Can you please upload your theme's header.phtml file ?

Comment: Yes, I have used custom code. @KishanPatadia

Comment: @MasudShaikh Please check my answer or paste your code here in your question.

Comment: I have uploaded header.ptml code @RohanHapani

Comment: @MasudShaikh Please check my updated answer. I modified your code.

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you @KishanPatadia

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Ok, I will update you @RohanHapani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this below line in your header.phtm file :

```
<span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
```

Comment: I have uploaded your code all top menu is hidden.

Comment: Hi, It is working fine. Name display on all pages.

Comment: Okay. You can accept answer :) If it's helpful :)

Comment: It is default magento2 functionality. But I want to custom name because i am login to one customer to another customer. When I log in another customer name showing the previous customer name.

Comment: I think you need to add customer.js file using knockout way. You can take reference from this file. It's better way to display customer name => vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

Comment: Can you explain how to add customer.js file using knockout way.

Comment: Yes. for that I added file path here. In your magento go to this path =>  vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml here you can see this inside <script> tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85693/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */

$ObjectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
$customerSession = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');




//$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('about-us'); ?>">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('contact-us'); ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>">My Orders</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('wishlist'); ?>">Wish List</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('ordertracking'); ?>">Track Order</a></li>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Codism\Csr\Block\Index\TopMenu')
    ->setTemplate('Codism_Csr::menu.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>

<?php if($isLoggedIn) {?>
<li>Hi, <?php echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); ?></li>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you.

Comment: I have tried. it is the same issue on the product page.

Comment: Did you refresh Magento caches ?

Comment: I have cleaned the cache. Condition is true but the only print ***Hi*** message. Customer name is not getting me.

Comment: This issue facing me only on the product page...Another page is working fine.